# Execute multiple %s commands in VIM always give me the error E488: Trailing characters

Tags: vim

I know that we have many questions (and answers) about this, but until now I couldn't solve my problem. I just need to execute these commands (and other ones) in the same line:

```
%s/request_snapshot\zs\s*=\s*true/ = false
%s/primary_dev\zs\s*=\s*"[^"]*"/ = "vnic"
```

I already tried:

```
%s/request_snapshot\zs\s*=\s*true/ = false | %s/primary_dev\zs\s*=\s*"[^"]*"/ = "vnic"
%s#request_snapshot\zs\s*=\s*true# = false | %s#primary_dev\zs\s*=\s*"[^"]*"# = "vnic"
%s#request_snapshot\zs\s*=\s*true# = false \| %s#primary_dev\zs\s*=\s*"[^"]*"# = "vnic"
```

and nothing. A very good answer would be to not worry about substitute the "/" by any other character, because I need to execute many commands and this is going to be very painful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Single substitution commands do not need the last separator (usually a slash, `/`) as it can be assumed. When you execute multiple commands by using the `|` then you need to make sure you have the final separator.

```
:%s/foo/bar
:%s/hello/world
```

Would become:

```
:%s/foo/bar/e | %s/hello/world/e
```

Note: I also added the `e` flag which suppresses errors if a substitution does not occur as this will stop the pipeline.

So your final command looks like this:

```
%s/request_snapshot\zs\s*=\s*true/ = false/e | %s/primary_dev\zs\s*=\s*"[^"]*"/ = "vnic"/e
```

Comment: Both answers are very good, but I liked the "e" option. Thank you so much for you and for FDinoff. After I'm going to study functions to check how can I put everything there.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution would be to create a function and then call that function. Since you can put each substitute command on its own line.

If you really want to chain them you must terminate the substitute command.

```
%s/request_snapshot\zs\s*=\s*true/ = false/
```

By putting a trailing slash (seperator) at the end of each of the substitutions.

So

```
%s/request_snapshot\zs\s*=\s*true/ = false/ | %s/primary_dev\zs\s*=\s*"[^"]*"/ = "vnic"
                                          ^
```

would be a valid substitution that can be chained.

The reason your original thinks it has trailing characters is that the pipe does not end a substitution. The slash after the `%s` ends the substitution. And `primary_dev\zs\s*=\s*"[^"]*"/ = "vnic"` does not constitute valid flags.